# Intersection for approximately equal objects

Tags: python, set, operators, intersection, equality

I'm detecting objects in images and trying different detection algorithms.  I want to compare the results of the algorithms over my dataset.  I've stored the results of each algorithm as a list of [filepath,detection_box_coordinates,otherstuff].  I'd like to consider two detections to be the same iff filepaths are the same and the overlap in the detection boxes is above some threshold.  I want to produce for any two algorithm results A and B, the lists only_in_A, only_in_B, and in_both.  I was hoping to find "one and preferably only one obvious way" of doing this, but my searches so far have produced several, not-necessarily-obvious ways.

Focusing on calculating in_both, I've considered doing the following:

1. Looping through every element of each list and comparing them
2. Sorting and partitioning the lists by filepath and then for each filepath, looping through the elements in each list
3. [x for x in itertools.product(A,B) and match(x)] with a custom match function
4. Making a class Detection and defining __eq__ to be my matching function
5. Implementing my own Intersector class as seen here: [Python intersection with custom equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846222/python-intersection-with-custom-equality)
6. Using a lambda function

Right now I can see the following cons to these ideas:

1. Very slow
2. Still slower than set operations and a bunch of code that might be reinventing the wheel
3. Probably slow and memory intensive
4. __eq__ would be reflexive and symmetric but not transitive.  Also, it would be possible for two items to have __eq__ return true but have different hashes.
5. Same as above.  Not sure about performance.
6. Don't have a clear idea of how to implement yet.

Which of my ideas are good or terrible?  Is there an obvious way I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Detection class would be a good idea with some modification:

```
class Detection():
    Instances = dict()
    In_A = dict()
    In_B = dict()
    def __new__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        if filepath in Detection.Instances.keys():
            _instance = Detection.Instances[filepath]
        else:
            _instance = super(Detection, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return _instance

    def __init__(self,filepath,coords,other,From_Algo):     
        if From_Algo = "A"  
            self.filepath = filepath 
            self.coords_A = coords
            self.in_A = True    
            self.other_A = other
            Detection.In_A[filepath] = self # Make sure that filepath is hashable
        if From_Algo = "B"  
            self.filepath = filepath 
            self.coords_B = coords
            self.in_B = True    
            self.other_B = other
            Detection.In_B[filepath] = self # Make sure that filepath is hashable
        Detection.Instances[filepath]=self # Make sure that filepath is hashable

    @classmethod
    def Check_coord_relation(cls,A_coords,B_coords):
        ...
        # compare A_coords and B_coords
        ...
        return Result

    @classmethod
    def Get_In_Both(cls):
        cls._Get_In_Both = [Det in Det for cls.Instances.values() if (hasattr(Det,"In_A") and hasattr(Det,"In_B") and cls.Check_coord_relation(Det.coords_A,coords_B))]

    @classmethod
    def Get_Only_In_A(cls):
        cls._Only_In_A = [Det in Det for cls.In_A.values() if Det not in cls._Get_In_Both]

    @classmethod
    def Get_Only_In_B(cls):
        cls._Only_In_B = [Det in Det for cls.In_B.values() if Det not in cls._Get_In_Both]

    @classmethod
    def Calc_Interseciton(cls):
        cls.Get_In_Both()
        cls.Get_Only_In_A()
        cls.Get_Only_In_B()
```

You can use the __new__ to check if the instance is already exists therefore the different attributes from the algos can be updated, after that the class can handle all of the instances that created.

First check the detection which are in both algos, the remove them form A and B.

I was not able to try this out, i hope this will help or give you new ideas.

The class variables seems not required to be dictionaries but dictionaries are really fast.